# Failed to update data in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, angular11

I am trying to build a .net core web api + Angular11(Full-Stack) project.I successfully created Add Data to DB in my back_End.but I am facing an issue when I trying to update my data.
here is my code:-

question.component.html

```
<mat-card >

  <mat-card-title>
    <span *ngIf="question.Id">Edit Question</span>
    <span *ngIf="!question.Id">Edit Question</span>
  </mat-card-title>

<mat-card-content>

<form>
   
    <mat-form-field class="fullwidth">
      <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="question.text" name="question" matInput placeholder="Question">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field  class="fullwidth">
      <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="question.correctAnswer" name="correctAnswer" matInput placeholder="Correct Answer">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field  class="fullwidth">
      <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="question.answer1" name="answer1" matInput placeholder="Wrong Answer 1">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="fullwidth">
      <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="question.answer2" name="answer2" matInput placeholder="Wrong Answer 2">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field class="fullwidth">
      <mat-label>Question</mat-label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="question.answer3" name="answer3" matInput placeholder="Wrong Answer 3">
    </mat-form-field>
  
  </form>
</mat-card-content>


<mat-card-actions>
    <button (click)="post(question)" mat-button>POST</button>
</mat-card-actions>


</mat-card>
```

questions.component.html  `(please no doubt.above is "question component" this is "questions component" **s**)`

```
<mat-card >

    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-list *ngFor=" let question of questions">

            <mat-list-item class="clickLink"  (click)="api.selectQuestion(question)">{{question.text}}</mat-list-item>

        </mat-list>
    </mat-card-content>
    
    
    <mat-card-actions>
        <button (click)="post(question)" mat-button>POST</button>
        <button (click)="put(question)" mat-button>EDIT</button>
    </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
```

question.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {ApiService} from './api.service'

@Component({

   selector:'question',
   templateUrl:'./question.component.html'

})

export class QuestionComponent{

    question: { text?: string;correctAnswer?:string;answer1?: string;answer2?:string;answer3?:string;Id?:any;  } = {}


    constructor(private api:ApiService){}

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.api.questionSelected.subscribe(question=>this.question=question);
    }

    post(question)
    {
        this.api.postQuestion(question);
    }
}
```

questions.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {ApiService} from './api.service'

@Component({

   selector:'questions',
   templateUrl:'./questions.component.html'

})

export class QuestionsComponent{

    question: { text?: string;correctAnswer?:string;answer1?: string;answer2?:string;answer3?:string  } = {}
    questions 


    constructor(public api:ApiService){}


    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.api.getQuestions().subscribe(res=>{

           this.questions=res;
        });
    }

    post(question)
    {
        this.api.postQuestion(question);
    }

    put(question)
    {
        this.api.putQuestions(question);
    }
}
```

api.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()

export class ApiService{

    private selectedQuestion=new Subject<any>();
    questionSelected=this.selectedQuestion.asObservable();

     constructor(private http:HttpClient){}

         postQuestion(question)
         {

            this.http.post ('https://localhost:44362/api/questions',question).subscribe(res=>{

                console.log(res)
            })
                  
         }

         getQuestions()
         {

          return  this.http.get ('https://localhost:44362/api/questions');
                  
         }

         putQuestions(question)
         {
            this.http.put (`https://localhost:44362/api/questions/${question.id}`,question).subscribe(res=>{

                console.log(res)
            })
         }

         selectQuestion(question)
         {
               this.selectedQuestion.next(question);
         }
}
```

Here is my Output with Error:-

[image]

When i click "Edit" button for edit.then i found above error.

i don't understand what's wrong in my code.how i resolve this issue.i am an absolute beginner in Angular.plase help.

Answer (score 0):

> this.http.put (`https://localhost:44362/api/questions/${question.id}`,question).subscribe(

> PUT https://localhost:44362/api/questions/undefined 400

Firstly, based on console error, we can find that the actual value of `question.id` you passed through URL is `undefined`, so please check if it should be modified with `question.Id`.

To troubleshoot the issue, you can check the actual request and data you posted in browser developer tool Network tab, and check if something wrong with request headers or posted data.

Besides, please check if you return a `BadRequestResult` from your action method, like below.

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
public IActionResult Edit(int id, Question question)
{
    if (id != question.Id)
    {
        return new BadRequestResult();
    }

    //...
```

Comment: already I have written this code in my backend.I am found this is my "Id" issue. my angular app can't pick my "id". but successfully pick my all-string type data.but I don't understand all data is picked, but why not id?"id" is not visible in my window but it's individually works!! how i resolve this issue.

Comment: I am try to ```<mat-list-item class="clickLink"  (click)="api.selectQuestion(question)">{{question.ID}}</mat-list-item>``` I am trying to display my "id"for check id works or not.but it's not visible in my window.i think main problem i found intiger type id.for that it's undefined.how i relsove that.

Comment: If you output the question via `console.log(question)` within `putQuestions(question)` function code block, what does it look like?

Comment: ```zone-evergreen.js:2863 PUT https://localhost:44362/api/questions/undefined 400``` found this error in my console.

Comment: And your `question` class defined on angular side seems not have property for storing `Id`.

Comment: @feri Han I understand but don't understand what should I do for resolving that. how I will properly storing "id: in my angular.or what should I do to pass "Id" to edit my data?  if you have any better process for pass id. please share.